# MySQL Workbench ERROR 1292: 1292: Incorrect date value: 'CURDATE()' for column 'StartDate' at row 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

in Result Grid->insert new row->Add SQL Scrip to database
Also fails with CURDATE(); CURDATE; 'CURDATE()', CURRENT_DATE(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

```
INSERT INTO `advantagedb`.`quests` (`QuestID`, `QuestName`, `Description`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `Reward`) VALUES ('2', 'q2', 'qq2', 'CURDATE()', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)', '13');
```

ERROR 1292: 1292: Incorrect date value: 'CURDATE()' for column 'StartDate' at row 1
SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `advantagedb`.`quests` (`QuestID`, `QuestName`, `Description`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `Reward`) VALUES ('2', 'q2', 'qq2', 'CURDATE()', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)', '13')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt with `CURDATE()`, without using the quotes `'` or `"`. Include the error message and the SQL statement to your question. Using `CURDATE()` without quotes should work just fine. Also add the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your `quests` table to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single-quotes from your expressions.

`CURDATE()` is a call to a function which will return the current date.

`'CURDATE()'` is not a call to that function. It's just a string literal. Strings in a format like '2023-11-10' can be converted to a date, but other formats won't convert. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html for more details on date formats supported by MySQL.